# jquery .scroll not working, click works fine

Tags: jquery

I know this question is pretty simple and I have used .scroll plenty of im times and it has worked so I have no idea what I could be wrong.
The following code works fine.

```
$(window).click(function(){
    $(document).find('#center').css('display','none');
    $(document).find('#up').css('display','inline');
});
```

But when I change it to the following nothing happens

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(document).find('#center').css('display','none');
    $(document).find('#up').css('display','inline');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with your code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZbLem for working answer

```
   // JS

   $(document).scroll(function(){
      $('#center').css('display','none');
      $('#up').css('display','inline');
      alert('Scroll is working!');
   });


  // html 

 <div class="container">

 <div id="center">center</div>
 <div id="up">up</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: sorry my fault i was confusing scroling and mouseover